# Opencv contour 1D discrete Fourier transform

Tags: c++, opencv

A problem happened about Fourier descriptor：  if a contour has K point，then let

s（k）= x（k）＋i y（k），k = 0,1，...,K-1.

the s(k) discrete Fourier transform is

a(u)=∑s（k）*e^(-i2πuk/K), k = 0,1，...,K-1.

I want to inverse the contour with a(p) ,p=0,1...,P，the P is less than K.
But when use dft function in Opencv:

dft(inputarray,outputarray,DFT_INVERSE,0);

the output array has the same size with input array, how can I get a K points contour with P parameters a(p)?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

actually the output array size should be equal to the input array size, revise the mathematical model of the DFT https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mdft/Mathematics_DFT.html

Comment: The essence of the link should be included in your answer; links on the internet tend to go stale.